# ASP.NET REST web service with token authentication and custom tables and custom privileges managing

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-token-authentication

I would like to create an ASP.NET web service with a classic token authentication, I've read some tutorial to create it, but each one of it will create new tables, in my case already exists a users table, and a custom table for rights management so that are not the best way in my case...

I followed this tutorial:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/
everything works with the tables generated by it, is there at this point a way to redirect everything to my tables and perform custom managing for privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could provide your own UserStore implementation and feed that to the UserManager in the AuthRepository.